# Why isn't the id being saved in this simple Active Record example?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

This is a newbie question about Ruby on Rails and Active Record. I created a rails app, a sqlite table, and a model class called `Thing` to map to the table. Then I ran the rails console, as below. Why is the `id` field not being saved correctly?

```
irb(main):005:0> Thing.all
  Thing Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things"
=> []
irb(main):006:0> t = Thing.new :name => 'test'
=> #<Thing id: nil, name: "test", somedate: nil>
irb(main):007:0> t.id
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> t.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (3.4ms)  INSERT INTO "things" ("name", "somedate") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", "test"], ["somedate", nil]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):010:0> Thing.all
  Thing Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "things".* FROM "things"
=> [#<Thing id: nil, name: "test", somedate: nil>]
irb(main):011:0> t.id
=> 1
```

In sqlite;

```
sqlite> .schema things
CREATE TABLE things (id int primary key, name text, somedate date);
```

The model:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is little bit confusing. But I guess your schema is problematic. Did you define `id` field explicitly in your migration file?

I'm saying this because, the primary field should also be auto incremented. To make sure i've just checked in my computer. For a table my schema is like:

```
CREATE TABLE "albums" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "user_id" integer,......
```

Here you can see the difference with your one.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks. I had manually created the table. It should probably throw an error about the definition of the ID column.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that if you run `rake db:migrate` it will create your things table with an auto-incrementing id column. Which will work the way you were expecting. I would not recommend creating your tables by hand.